# how to get the array not by key in loop?

Tags: php

There is a loop:

```
foreach($data['data'] as $value => $key){
    //ODO
}
```

And array `$data['user']`.
Format array is:

```
array(2) {
  [472]=>
  array(15) {
  ...
  }
[456] => 
array(16){
}
}
```

How I can get element of array for each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Any example of current and desired output you could show?

Comment: What's the error? No error? Sorry we don't do homework

Comment: Now extended question, please see

Comment: so let me understand... you have 2 `$data` arrays, one with first dimension named data and second name user and those 2 match? This question is so vague... please try to be more explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
foreach (array_keys($data['user']) as $key) {
    echo $data['user'][$key];
    echo $data['data'][$key];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

2nd attempt. You can use `reset()`, `current()` and [`next()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) to step to the next item in an array. This way, you can run a cursor over the second array while you iterator over the first:

```
$users = $data['user'];
reset($users);
foreach($data['data'] as $value => $key)
{
  $res = current($users);
  next($users);
  // Use $res here.
}
```

Note, you named your variables `$value` and `$key` in the loop, but they should be vice versa. The first one is the key.

Normally you would use `next` in a do..while loop, because next advances to the next item and returns that. But in this case, you have the different loop, so you need to combine `current` and `next` to get the current item, and advance to the next row afterwards.

Alternatively, you can use `each()`:

```
$users = $data['user'];
reset($users);
foreach($data['data'] as $value => $key)
{
  list($userKey, $res) = each($users);

  // Use $res here.
}
```

Comment: Key is not $i //0,1,2

Comment: @Balmus $i is 0,1,2... ! The answer is correct!

Comment: No, I think I know what he means. $data['user'] has numeric keys, but they are explicitly set keys that are not in order. So the first item is not `0` but for instance `456`.

Comment: I need something as like `currect()` for each iteration

Comment: You mean `next()`? See my update.